# Can I deserialize previously serialized data after adding fields to the class?

Tags: c#, serialization

If I have a serializable class, e.g.:

```
[Serializable]
public class SaveData {
   public int positionX = 42;
   public int positionY = 69;
}
```

and serialize it into a file using a `BinaryFormatter.Serialize()` and a `FileStream`, and later ship an update of the app with an updated class `SaveData` to save additional data, e.g.:

```
[Serializable]
public class SaveData {
   public int positionX = 42;
   public int positionY = 69;
   public string name = "Mr Foo";
}
```

will old saves still load properly? (again, using `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize()` and `FileStream`)

And if it works, will it use `"Mr Foo"` as default value?

Comment: You're going to want to take a look at Microsoft's official [Version tolerant serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/version-tolerant-serialization) "blog" post

Comment: @MindSwipe Thank you, that looks like a good relevant read. Will look into it!

Comment: I did actually try this now (it was a loong time ago I used binaryformatter) and it failed when deserialize, however if I marked the new field as [OptionalField] it worked, but no value was set (=null) to the name-field.

Answer (score 2):

After @MindSwipe gave me a link to a great read in the comments, I want to provide an answer to my own question to help out future search engine users with the same question.

So if this is my `SaveData` class to begin with:

```
[Serializable]
public class SaveData {
    public int positionX = 42;
    public int positionY = 69;
}
```

Then, if I ship an update that adds a field to this class, I should do it like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class SaveData {
    public int positionX = 42;
    public int positionY = 69;

    [OptionalField(VersionAdded = 2)]
    public string name = "Mr Foo";

    [OnDeserialized()]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext sc)
    {
        // set default value for optional fields like this!
        // deserialization will not take the initialization value
        // from the field definition above!
        if(name == null) name = "Mr Foo";
    }
}
```

Note that all fields that are added later *must* have the attribute `OptionalField`, ideally with a `VersionAdded` to it.

Here a couple tips ("best practices"), provided by Microsoft in an article called [Version tolerant serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/version-tolerant-serialization) (because you never know, if that link will work forever):

- Never remove a serialized field.
- Never apply the `NonSerializedAttribute` attribute to a field if the attribute was not applied to the field in the previous version.
- Never change the name or the type of a serialized field.
- When adding a new serialized field, apply the `OptionalFieldAttribute` attribute.
- When removing a `NonSerializedAttribute` attribute from a field (that was not serializable in a previous version), apply the `OptionalFieldAttribute` attribute.
- For all optional fields, set meaningful defaults using the serialization callbacks unless `0` or `null` as defaults are acceptable.